# Why is the total field for this bar chart not encoded into the correct x axis position on this vega lite spec?

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite

I'm trying to show the bar chart total count along this chart ([vega-lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqULKQI4aEMSSCGcCIoNGTZ1AG1QsJACdMABSRk4AUUGI4szACCAB40EAAa+gBiSLIABAHOsQDKMGwA7lBIEHpKDs5uHt6+-sGhAJpoAIwADLkwTq7uXj66-gDijmwMOABCAJ76AJJxOJ1kjqZmdQ0FzcWBIeEAwnCCggBqlnro0XEJmMmpGVk5IHmNhS1+mB1dvX0ra5vG2yDZxp4AnACO3wASABYAGzEAAcggAigFqiAAL4Kez1fJNIqtBahCLoAAicFIgjYODgjmSODYmGEZCw5nOs1R11KEAqqFqZyRFzmaNu3X6+gAKmxlGxqWzaVcSoswo8Nlt9Di8QSiSSyRSqdNkZd5lz7lLniZ9O8yG0EECAZEAGaVOCggBSAGYAOySOEI1kzFFi9HhfRtHRwWK8uAnYm8xxIGg+RzCt0atEMpm2sRq9l09qdbkDdDDWKjNjjSZR9Uc+kSnUy9A+3T+wPZYOh8NEgvJj1a-qll761YML6-QEg8FQmHwxHRovijFRGLxRIpdKZbKN0XzONoe2J12FlM3NP3IYjMYTCBTddNpcl1bS9s7Sf7Q6zk4L92a7et8+617vLs-f7AsGQ6HO4cNw9BlMRAOVVgVYkklJckaEpTAHxjYtyjQAEWRpR9OWfDMQCzHM80PRDR09SVXzLMDcQgwkoJglUEKTRcsLuF8nnIj9u2-Ps-0HF0MKQscvXLX0qyDf06wjIjN2XVAxHQkVMOuFscLw-d8wYhSBNI1jLxACs-QDUSQzDCT1P4rdmIeMidPYr9e1-AcAOPRjkMEkBdinA4Z2OedTOI6SajkkdNyU3ds1UwjfKks9tL1K89mnI451OPjiKUttYreTsOLs-t-yHJyNJI2VKPxailVg+DJOAxYmSBQKgKfCzQvwg8jxSqKMXS15wNKxVoOVODVQKsy0qsjKbJ7H9cp4wCT1jCVvWEgyazE4yG0i6qUJk+q5sU7DmvCtr5LMkCusWytlsVIz60jDbGvTM70Amzj7Ly3jjr8hbsRKyDyroqrTy2uq7qY9MDtzVqAfmzqxu6n6yv6iqhva5tsMezKPlsqbuMclHAdc9yby8pKoZcpkApBvamszPcIbU4bPphmLXkJhK7x8hngrR2GO0xyauIc-K8eh1y9JElbrpMznNsZFc12FqmwZpsK6Yi6X8a0i8MrFy7azW271dB7UeaerKsYFt7ZuczTivlBHaMG+jDbJlcdut8yldw2mCKOoKZc1t9baovqHcqynUws9HnpynGhY+jqCevNnvOS+OZfJ6o3cKkLsTkVO-Y19HWc8xL73Dj3jeZ3nPEqBA2jYYgAVtQYyBqW1bVxtONfO-Tqyu8T1udgSmU+LORv25WWvphXNPRnW+71m7SYjh6TYxz9+demah6KuKPNvFPl89DOx9SiewLzo-TrX4uD5J8vRqr03BBruuG6blu247uOC5F0Cet+ojf65dpKglPlzamXsVY+yvtFLWcM7YhwGmHHej94G8w3i9aandf4uVAvPQyA8DYz2PlUTOD9z5YkviAuBgchIXQXqtJeFDI5r3eK-eujdm6t2qO3HBDU-5B16jRZByMu4ixHvLcRisdyT0OrApm6DvqIJEUjJ2JC0F0PXtlbGgt3q4JtnvImpcOYkP8uQ1BlDqE72vk-NyScS7s3zgImRLElEYw4e-bhX9+G7UMbpJajDJaDzMTVMh4DUaQKobIZxfiSJz0CYQ-WR9NFsVWJ4rhn9eHf30S4-xAD7aiPUdI4e4SWGe2ibE92tj3EFKQWolJ3M7HsNrpwj+PC+E-zybvex8VHGHxoVtCmlionWNCYorRt9iZlxGavZp6TWleKyZ03JcSQL6ACLIMk8BiRjJKaQ1AwyNFWJiQo5Ya9NnbMVHsgxFc3FaJaW-TJHSclW0Kus9Alz6DXNOYM2WqBbQRPurIi+vybG0PIl8nZsQbndNSdZBZTz2k+NhAAXXhCAQQSA+gNlsKAZAjgADWaBQCYD6ISfQTAnBwnygS4lmgQBkopegTAcAghOzNOGQQ+gADEmcYRKCMHBeQ6AfBmidsoIIaBQRKFZeyklIA2WjH0GaNgjhkCYAABSqEwAwBAlBxmMi1PydQggFCxAAOSUGqGaC1ABKGlSg-BQAFDQWQZAFVSoZZy1Yyh9CGrKMaskRgaVoqdbIF1yg3UeoZV60APrBB+vQAG8wTLXjfAYDETAdA1A0FIOYdweYKCsv0FGiA2aI1OyQIsBV2bySvHMIKZAbq0BmiMNkWEGKMzxpoL6-1+z1myvJa8LZCA3UhsFTWhldafD6HMOMGgSa22CGyLKmgUBCXWGXR2pQMhnD6CyFAPwUb3XOkZWwNgghs04DQHYEACak3gvHGu+t+gXCdEkHAKACF8oPv7bcuMQbTWpuHfoDNWac3ZvzS+2d6ATUht-b2xN-64X7Rg68JI6hdVHjTfoUd47uWIb7cmgdYSh3MpAOB-wkG82nELRMYtrwy0Vu-amugsGwKhBY5gVAsR32qyPKq9VagFWhACGQItua5BYjUBobdcAlCyD1UwIkkQ1Uav0LEa1Zoz1CY1byUD6AlMIBU5GMNZxL1qoVX+kjtyQrof0JhtQDAcOGZAPh7QhGlBquULintxGQDjAsgAeUcL5szGLMChlkBAPTt77BGCgAwLFJb0A0DNNq5z+rjkWViAAXgK7EAAOlAqeh4SvmttAodLmXdXZf2UpfLhWSuVIq7EAATNVjLOq9UGoa9hJreXisgH5IKNrlRzXVDtdNgt1hAvYVC+Fxykg2DjokwxtQ2w70ElLVxt1rGlA2afbLQVc2A1AYQ6ipQQXuhMAzDYY7ER0VXYwHAR2aBAUsjSIu+gaAxBiFtLCIAA))  but the labels don't seem to be positioned in the correct location across the x axis. They are all at the 1 position.

This is the encoding I'm using for the text marks:

```
{
  "mark": {
    "type": "text",
    "fill": "#000",
    "align": "left",
    "dx": 8,
    "text": {
      "expr": "format(datum.chartPageElementAxisYGroupTotal, '.0f')"
    }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "chartPageElementAxisYGroupTotal"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: chart with buggy total count position]

What's the problem? Is there a better way to do this with vega-lite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Your distinct count for Fan Art looks incorrect but I don't understand what your data or what you're trying to show.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "values",
    "values": [
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 10,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 0,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Todo",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selgGm64Ff1e8J37j"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 35,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 75,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 40,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 50,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 60,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 50,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 60,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 75,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 70,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 90,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 80,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 95,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "In progress",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "seluE9qqH46v8lQA0"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Game Teaser Trailer",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Developer Spotlight",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Fan Art Showcase",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Another one",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 100,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Another one",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      },
      {
        "chartPageElementAxisX": "Another one",
        "chartPageElementAxisY": 30,
        "chartPageElementGroupBy": "Done",
        "chartPageElementAxisXCellValue": "Another one",
        "chartPageElementGroupByCellValue": "selE1mGov43Ig1033"
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "chartPageElementAxisY",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "distinct",
          "axis": {"title": "", "domain": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "chartPageElementAxisX",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": "", "grid": false, "ticks": false},
          "sort": "ascending"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "chartPageElementAxisX", "title": "Project"},
          {
            "field": "chartPageElementAxisYGroupTotal",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": "Total"
          },
          {
            "field": "chartPageElementGroupBy",
            "title": "Status",
            "type": "nominal"
          },
          {
            "field": "chartPageElementAxisY",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "distinct",
            "title": "Distinct: Progress",
            "format": {"isAggregationData": false, "numberFormat": " .0f"},
            "formatType": "number"
          }
        ],
        "color": {
          "field": "chartPageElementGroupBy",
          "title": "Status",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "order": {"field": "groupByOrder"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fill": "#000",
        "align": "left",
        "dx": 8,
        "text": {"expr": "format(datum.chartPageElementAxisYGroupTotal, '.0f')"}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "aggregate": [
            {
              "op": "distinct",
              "field": "chartPageElementAxisY",
              "as": "chartPageElementAxisYGroupTotal"
            }
          ],
          "groupby": ["chartPageElementAxisX"]
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "chartPageElementAxisYGroupTotal",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "chartPageElementAxisX",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": "", "grid": false, "ticks": false},
          "sort": "ascending"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "if(datum.chartPageElementGroupBy === \"In progress\", 3,if(datum.chartPageElementGroupBy === \"Done\", 2,if(datum.chartPageElementGroupBy === \"Todo\", 1, 0)))",
      "as": "groupByOrder"
    }
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 553
}
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response. The data is variable since it can be provided by users. 

Fixing the encoding and still having the issue made me realize the problem, the y axis aggregation counts distinct values per group, but the text mark needs to sum the counts of distinct values per group. 

Thanks for your response!